# See progress in Files (Nautilus)

Tags: monitoring, file-copy, nautilus

I am trying to copy a directory containing multiple subdirectories and files to an external drive. It is taking a long time (24+ hours). I copied in Files on Fedora 23 instead of `cp -v` on the terminal. Is it still possible to check what is going on (which files are being copied at the moment) so that I can find out which directories are taking a long time?

The image below is all I can see at the moment.

[image]

Comment: You could try with `watch lsof -a -p $(pgrep nautilus) +D /path/to/where/you/copy` and in the output, in the `SIZE/OFF` column you should see the bytes count for the current file being copied (updating every two seconds). Note this requires you copy some large files (otherwise you won't see any output unless you decrease the time interval e.g. watch -n 0.2` and even then...)

Comment: @don_crissti This sounds great! I need to copy the same things again - I'll try it then.

Answer (score 1):

Within Nautilus preferences I don't see an appropriate option.

In my case, I had to copy terabytes of data from a failing drive (the transfer rates were very unstable). I was using Krusader for this, which provides a progress bar via KDE's notification icon.

While researching I discovered an amazing command line utility `rsync`.

- `rsync -r --info=progress2 /source /destination` should give you overall progress (i.e. of the sum of data to be transferred, not per file) of recursive directory copying. `man rsync` advises not to use the `-v` option with `--info=progress2`, but it will do no harm.
- `rsync -rvhP /source /destination` should give you exactly what you are looking for: the progress of recursive directory copying per file, with current transfer rate and expected completion time.

Comment: See my comment under the other answer. But before that, read the question again.

Comment: @don_crissti I didn't expect my answer to be upvoted, let alone accepted, but the more you sustain a tall poppy syndrome by spitting on answers like this the less inclined other people will be to help each other next time. This site is about cooperation, not penalising.

Comment: @captcha - you must be new on this site... If you actually bothered reading the question you would see the OP wants to _"check what is going on (which files are being copied at the moment)"_.  None of the answers here helps him as both answers offer alternatives to copying via file manager. And if you think your answer helps the OP then read the question **again**, OP clearly says _"I copied in Files [...] instead of `cp -v` on the terminal."_ (and confirms he knows about `cp -v` in a comment under your answer). As to penalising / downvoting: you're barking up the wrong tree. It wasn't me.

Comment: @don_crissti: I am frequently surprised by the amount of excellent tools *nix systems offer. Without answers that go beyond the original question I would never have discovered these tools. Your comment about `watch lsof` expanded my knowledge again (thanks), but in essence even you did not answer the question as it is not _in Nautilus_. ;-)

Comment: You misunderstood the question so I invite you to read it again. It's not about doing something _in Nautilus_ or _outside Nautilus_. It is about detecting which file is being currently processed by Nautilus and the progress of the copy operation. So my comment (while not perfect) _does answer_ the question.

Comment: @XavrasWyzryn Thanks. I need to start using rsync instead of cp for such copies!

Answer (score -1):

Run the `cp` command with the `-v` argument in an xterm.

Comment: How would this help the OP find out which files are being copied at the moment by _Files_ (`nautilus`) ?

Comment: @captcha Thanks. I know `cp -v` but I didn't use that because I wanted to see some indication of progress (how many files copied, what percentage/time remains etc), which is shown in GUI but not with `cp` on terminal.

Comment: @captcha Comments exist.